# TypeScript(Nodejs error) Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, oop

I have a nodejs App and am using Typescript for it and have implemented Classes and interfaces for the Models for Db . I have a model User class with interface too .I simply want to send notification and am using Puhser basic code like this

```
  
  let pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID,
    key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    secret: process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET,
    cluster: process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER
    });
  pusher.trigger('notifications', 'user_added', user, req.headers['x-socket-id']);
```

I thought i would be simple but its giving the following error on all the fields like appId,key etc

**(property) appId: string | undefined**
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(45, 5): The expected type comes from property 'appId' which is declared here on type 'Options'

i tried using pusher variable as interface but pusher is thirdparty system i tried

```
let pusher = new Pusher({
                        const appId: string = process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID,
                        const key: string = process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
                        const secret: string = process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET,
                        const cluster: string = process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER
                    });
type here
```

Comment: Is ```PUSHER_APP_ID``` (etc..) defined in the process' enviroment?

Comment: Make a sure your environment variables are set.

Comment: the return type you get from process.env will be string or undefined because it could either exist or not so you have two options, you either define the types you pass to your DB as string | undefined or you implement a typeguard to guarantee the correct type being passed in

Comment: Yes all the variables are stored in Env File

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the environment variables to string.

```
let pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID as string,
    key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY as string,
    secret: process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET as string,
    cluster: process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER as string,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript does not know what variables will be defined in your environment at compile time so it will assume that `process.env.{anything}` may or may not be defined (i.e. it will be `string|undefined`). If you know for certain that it will be defined then you can say:

```
  let pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID!,
    key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY!,
    secret: process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET!,
    cluster: process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER!
    });
```

The non-null assertion operator `!` tells TypeScript that you know for certain that at the given point the variable will not be `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

becuase `process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID` value is undefined console.log(process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID) check value

Comment: well i have saved these values in env file but as in strict mode the Vscode is throwing error so i havent started the server yet

Comment: try these let pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID as string,
  key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  secret: process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET,
  cluster: process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER
  });

or past below line before code
 //@ts-ignore

Answer (score 0):

The return type you get from `process.env` is going to be of type `yourRequiredType | undefined` because it could exist or not and that is what Typescript is trying to tell you.

You have two options:

1. You can define the properties of your object to be the desired Type or undefined;
2. You can implement a Typeguard to guarantee the correct type being passed in like so:

   const stringTypeGuard = (x: unknown): x is string => typeof x === string

before you pass your object to the db you can use this to guarantee your properties are what you want

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's better to tupple your way out of it.
Since TypeScript can't be sure that the env var is set, it can be either string or undefined. To remedy this, I always do it like this

```
let pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID || "",
    key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY || "",
    secret: process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET || "",
    cluster: process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER || ""
});
```

This will look at the env var, and if it's not set, it will simply make it "". This will guarantee that this always will be a string